# Extract rows where the X column is equal to the Y column using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2 3347485 rs7559860 C G AA=G||| GT  G
2 3347492 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347560 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347576 . A T AA=A||| GT  A
2 3347577 . G C AA=G||| GT  G
```

What I want to do is get the lines where the 4th column is equal to the 8th (last one). In this case the first line will be dropped.

Is there a way to do this using bash?

My desire output should look like this:

```
2 3347492 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347560 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347576 . A T AA=A||| GT  A
2 3347577 . G C AA=G||| GT  G
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tailor-made job for `awk` since we're dealing with row/column of data:

```
awk '$4 == $8' file

2 3347492 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347560 . C T AA=C||| GT  C
2 3347576 . A T AA=A||| GT  A
2 3347577 . G C AA=G||| GT  G
```

`$4 == $8` checks for equality of 4th col with 8th col.

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: Wow! That looks extremely straightforward, my file is huge, but while it's running do it will have a problem with the delimiters of the file?

Comment: Worked perfectly!